# Make success messages disappear after few second :(

Tags: python, django

it is my layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">

    <title>Mikayıl`ın Bloğu</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% include "includes/navbar.html" %}




        <div style = "margin-top : 100px; margin-bottom:100px;" class = "container">

            {% include "includes/messages.html" %}



            {% block body %}

            {% endblock body %}

        </div>


    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'%} "></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js'%} "></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // messages timeout for 10 sec 
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.message').fadeOut('slow');
            }, 10000); // <-- time in milliseconds, 1000 =  1 sec

            // delete message
            $('.del-msg').live('click',function(){
                $('.del-msg').parent().attr('style', 'display:none;');
            })
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and it is my message.html  this file is intor the folder in templates/includes but i added this  into layout.html to

```
{% if messages %}

    {% for message in messages %}
    {% if message.tags == "info" %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ message }}</div>

    {% else %}
    <div  class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</div>

    {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

i looked stackoverflow there was topic same as me i tried but i couldnt reach my goal

but i cant make succes message which one disappear after 5 second who can help me :)

Comment: In your js content, you use selector `.message` but you have alert in your message class. Can you change selector to `.alert`?

Comment: ohh thank you very much it is working now how stupid i am i m new and i have lack of english thats why sometimes i cant anyway THANKYOU!

Comment: I've added an answer that you can accept. Sometimes, we forget to update pasted codes according to our need. It is a pleasure to me that I can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class names are different in your js and html parts, just change `.message` to `.alert` to work.